# How do you write an SQL query to select rows that lie within plus or minus thirty seconds of a time field?

Tags: sql

I have a table A that contains (Name, Year, Day, Time) and table B contains (UserID, Time_written)..

I'm not sure how to construct a query that will select and output rows from table A that lie within plus or minus thirty seconds of every row in table..

Comment: What do you need table B for?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the date operators in db2, but the trick is to join on

```
A.time < dateadd(B.time, 30 seconds) AND A.time > dateadd(B.time, -30 seconds)
```

On SQL Server I would write

```
select A.* from A inner join B on
     A.time < DATEADD("s", 30, B.time) AND
     A.time > DATEADD("s", -30, B.time)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Albin is close, but DB2 does not have a `DATEADD()` function, it uses ANSI date math:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM tabA a
JOIN tabB b
  ON a.time BETWEEN (b.time - 30 SECOND) AND (b.time + 30 SECOND)
```

(This assumes that `time` is a `TIMESTAMP` field.)

Comment: If the answer works for, there should be an option to accept it (there should be a checkmark to the left that you can click to do that).